# Como imprimir pagina

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, python-2.7, django-generic-views

Quero criar um template para impressão de dados porém estou meio perdido em como fazer isso, tenho um botão de nome print, o mesmo se encontra em uma tabela que contem o nome do cliente, telefone endereço etc ..., ao clicar nele ele deve pegar o id deste cliente e os dados do mesmo como nome, telefone, endereço ..., e colocar dentro do template print_page.html, que vai conter algumas coisas a mais como logo, nome da empresa ..., alguém sabe me dizer se tem como fazer isso com django direto no views ou se tenho que usar javascript ou alguma outra coisa?

Estava tentando fazer direto no views, mas acabei por notar que a minha logica não esta de todo o certo creio eu.

```
class PrintView(TemplateView):
    template_name = 'core/print_page.html'

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(PrintView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['print_page'] = Client.objects.get(pk=self.pk)
        return context
```

Dei uma pesquisada mas não encontrei nada relacionado ao que eu quero.

Desde já agradeço toda e qualquer ajuda.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bom, como você vai imprimir apenas uma linha do seu banco de dados, sugiro que utilize uma `DetailView` em vez de uma `TemplateView`, assim não precisa configurar o contexto:

```
class ClientPrintView(DetailView):
    model = Client
    template_name = 'core/print_page.html'
```

Faça o template conforme achar adequado. Se quiser que a janela de impressão apareça logo de cara, pode colocar um script em javascript no fim do template:

```
<script>
  (function(){
    window.print();
  })();
</script>
```

Comment: Show vlw @Pablo.